# How to test a table containing items when using protractor in Angular

Tags: angular, e2e-testing

The page is shown below consists of an image of a table containing a list of patients. I want to write an e2e test but I'm new to this.

How can I access the items in the table given the code below showing the table items and test them by checking the rows and also the columns and check if data exists?

## This is my list:

[image]

## code

```html
<table _ngcontent-c34="" class="col-md-12 mat-table" mat-table="" matsort="" role="grid" ng-reflect-data-source="[object Object]">
   <thead>
      <!---->
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-row ng-star-inserted" mat-header-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-43 cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="patientName" mattooltip="Sort by pa tient name" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-17" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Sort by pa tient name" ng-reflect-id="patientName">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for patientName">Patient</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-44 cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="age" mattooltip="Patient Age" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-18" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patient Age" ng-reflect-id="age">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for age">Age</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-45 cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="birth" mattooltip="Patient Birth Date" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-19" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patient Birth Date" ng-reflect-id="birth">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for birth"> Birth</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-46 cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="sex" mattooltip="Patient Gender" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-20" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patient Gender" ng-reflect-id="sex">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for sex">Sex</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-47 cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="location" mattooltip="Patients Location" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-21" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patients Location" ng-reflect-id="location">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for location">Location</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-48 cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="phone" mattooltip="Patient's phone number" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-22" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patient's phone number" ng-reflect-id="phone">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for phone"> Phone</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
         <th _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-header-cell ng-tns-c36-49 cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="lVisit" mattooltip="Patients Last Visit" role="columnheader" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-23" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Patients Last Visit" ng-reflect-id="lVisit">
            <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
               <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for lVisit">Last Visit</button>
               <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div>
                  <div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
                     <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </th>
         <!---->
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <!---->
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">Alextest Ktest</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">36</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/07/1983 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Test, Test</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 123 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">Another Name Name Last</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">0</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/09/2019 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Kenya, Kenya</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 0748828422 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">AnotherName2 LasName2</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">0</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/13/2019 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Kenya, Kenya</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 35234234234 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">John Doe</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">29</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/13/1990 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Kenya, Nairobi</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 1234567 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">06/10/2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">Lilo wanjiru</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> Invalid date </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">, </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">  </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">dfds ffdgdfg</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">0</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/14/2019 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Kenya, Nairobi</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 5129862770 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">dfds ffdgdfg</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> Invalid date </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">, </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">  </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">dfds ffdgdfg</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> Invalid date </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">, </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">  </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">dfds ffdgdfg</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> Invalid date </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">, </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">  </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
         <!---->
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-patientName mat-column-patientName ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"><a _ngcontent-c34="" class="patient-name">dsfsdf dfsfsd</a></td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-age mat-column-age ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">0</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-birth mat-column-birth ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 06/20/2019 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-sex mat-column-sex ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Male</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-location mat-column-location ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">Kenya, Nairobi</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-phone mat-column-phone ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> 0792345678 </td>
         <td _ngcontent-c34="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-lVisit mat-column-lVisit ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">No Record Yet</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot class="mat-table-sticky" style="bottom: 0px; position: sticky; z-index: 10;">
      <!---->
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into angular js [locators](https://www.protractortest.org/#/locators) and [repeaters](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater). The locators will help you to locate the element either by id, className, name, CSS, etc and then in case you generate your table using repeaters, then you can just write a loop to get you the rows and the columns present in the table and check if they contain data.

For more information refer to [Protractor API](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater)